# Error en fecha Laravel Excel

Tags: laravel-5, laravel, excel, laravel-excel

Estoy usando la librería **Laravel Excel** y hasta ahora me ha ido bien en muchos formatos distintos de ficheros, etc... La cosa es que ahora tengo el siguiente caso:

En el fichero excel me pasan una fecha en formato dd/mm/yyyy y sin tratarla ni nada hago un **dd($sheet->toArray());** de todo el contenido del fichero y me pone que la fecha es 01-01-1900 muy extraño, alguien sabe a que es debido eso? O como puedo hacer para indicarle por defecto un formato? O que simplemente me saque ese valor como string en lugar de **Carbon** ??

**CAPTURA:**

[image: resultado del dd($sheet->toArray());]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final he visto que a diferencia de otros sitios donde usaba la función me he fijado que en este caso estaba usando dos variables globales y en los otros casos solo una.

La he quitado un momento y he probado a cargar y ya me pintaba la fecha bien, he vuelto a dejar todo como estaba y me ha funcionado... Muy curioso.

```
Excel::selectSheetsByIndex(0)->load($url, function ($sheet) use($code, $account){

 }
```

He quitado la variable $account de dentro del use y sin más ha querido funcionar.